# Replacing a 20A 250V outlet

Tags: receptacle

We are trying to replace a 20A 250V single outlet that was installed in 1975. We have tried replacing it with a 15A 120V double outlet. When checking our completed work, the outlet tester read that the wires were reversed. We changed the wiring, and the outlet tester still read that the wires were reversed.

Comment: It's not "reversed". The magic 8-ball tester only tests voltage (broad range - typically 50V - 250V will all show the same) between each pair of pins. Normally neutral-ground will be 0V, so 120V on neutral (one of your hot pair) will *look like* neutral/hot reversed. Sort of. The real question is whether you have a neutral available or not. **Post a picture of the wires** plus **a picture of the breaker panel** and we might be able to sort this out.
See also my answer at https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/154053/socket-tester-all-indicators-light-up/154055#154055

Comment: How about a picture of hat you've got.

Comment: How many wires are there? If you have a black white and copper you can put a 120v receptacle in or if red , black, white and copper 2 circuits sharing the neutral called a multiwire branch circuit with your double pole breaker. So we need a bit more information. Those testers are really not much help unless everything is right or to trip a GFCI on a grounded GFCI receptacle. That’s why they are referred to as magic 8 ball testers.

Comment: Was the original outlet truly a 240v circuit?  If so, did you change the wiring in the breaker panel to make it a 120 volt circuit?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the outlet box please, as well as of the face of the old outlet?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to risk posting my comment as an answer.  If the original outlet was truly a 240 volt outlet (probably a cable of 2 wire and a ground) and you didn't change the wiring in the main panel by moving the white wire (of the circuit) to the neutral bussbar making it a 120 volt circuit, your still going to get 240 v on your new outlet.   The outlet has no way of changing 240 to 120, that's the role of the breaker panel connections. That assumes, Ed's comments about a MWBC dont' apply Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

***"You didn't slay the dragon!!!???"***
 ---- Fiona, *[Shrek](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSqVzY0Kd7A)*

### First, you have to rewire the circuit to 120V

Which means moving wires around back at the service panel.

You can't just slap a 120V socket on a 240V circuit, or you'll get 240V coming out of your 120V socket and you'll smoke anything you plug into it.

The white wire needs to be moved to the neutral bar, and it needs to be connected to neutral on the receptacle (silver screws).