# Outlet, breaker issue

Tags: circuit-breaker

New home. I replaced all the old outlets with decos and reinstalled. I plugged in a light, 2 prong, and no issue. I plugged in a tester to check see that the others were wired correctly and the green light came on for a second and then the breaker tripped. I removed all outlets , left wired, to look for a ground fault but nothing. Could this be a problem in the panel?

Comment: is the circuit protected by an AFCI or GFCI breaker?

Comment: Yes, does the breaker in question have a TEST button on it?

Comment: Did you accidentally hit the "GFCI Test" on the tester?  Also, be warned abut those testers with a green light.  They are a *much worse version* of [these things](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/113052/47125) because they don't even give you the raw "3 lights" data, they interpret it *for you*, and many interpretations are misleading and flat wrong, and we see people spend *hours* chasing problems that aren't actually there.